# Does Quantum mechanics predict (statistical) frequencies?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, probability, born-rule

I began reading a book by Bricmont and Zwirn (Philosophie de la mécanique quantique, as yet not translated). In a note (page 4), Bricmont writes (translation mine):

> Probability is a theoretical concept which can be identified, or not, with a frequency, depending on the idea one has about it. What the predictions of quantum mechanics bear on are empirically observable frequencies.

Is there something beyond the [Born rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Born_rule) which compels us to conceive of its predictions as [(statistical) frequencies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_%28statistics%29)? Did I miss such a rule?

Comment: I think they mean that the frequentist interpretation of probability theory is the only useful one for physics because all measurements are finite in length, i.e. one can never really take the limit from a frequency towards a probability. This is true for all of physics, not just quantum mechanics, so you don't need to look at the Born rule or any other QM specific  property.

Comment: I don't understand your reasonning : since we cannot take the limit of frequencies (to obtain a probability ?) we are compelled to conceive of probabilities as frequencies ? Furthermore, why is the "degree of belief" interpretation useless ?

Comment: "probability" is a mathematical term that does not have a counterpart in reality. In reality there are only frequencies and the frequentist interpretation together with the law of large numbers connects the two. Both are empirical assumptions that are backed by sufficient data to be accepted as true.

Comment: @GeorgK We are not compelled to conceive of probabilities as frequencies, but we are compelled to infer them from measurements of frequencies. Mathematical definition of probability envisions a sample space and a probability measure on it. Each point in the sample space determines a separate world with an alternative outcome of an experiment. We have no empirical access to these alternative worlds, so we rely on implications for repeated trials in a single world, i.e. on frequencies.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood correct your question(and the discussion below) :

In Quantum Mechanics we get some probabilities(in theory) for measuring certain eigenvalues of physical observables, that are, operators. Let's say you are making only one measurement and you get a certain price for that measurement. Can you say that the probabilities have been verified? Of course not. But when you make a lot of measurements, you start see those probabilities satisfied. Well, that is, we get a frequency of appearance of a certain eigenvalue. We verify those probabilities by taking a lot of measurements, concluding to frequencies: that is, how many times a certain price has make an appearance.

Hope I have understood your question and helped.

Comment: See also the comment in your question by Conifold.

Comment: To make my point clearer : I thought the quantum theory fathers had implemented the concept of probability and the users had to decide upon the interpretation and application of the concept, be it frequency, degree of belief etc... Whereas Bricmont seems to be telling that quantum theory deals with frequencies. My question is only : is it so ?

Comment: @GeorgK   , Hi again. Maybe I'm wrong on this but, at the end I don't think we could say in a paragraph that is this or that. I would say it's a matter of interpretation(not a bad think). I don't currently have a book I was reading by Ballentine(Quantum Mechanics Modern Development ) where the author argues about the correct interpretation on probability based on modern techniques and experiments. If you can search it in a library it might help you. Note that probability is a mathematical sense very difficult to understand in reality, Thus we talk for frequencies in QM or the tendency...

Comment: ... of a certain result to happen. Hope I helped.